# mongodb mongoose combine multiple documents as a single document with aggregated values

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have thousands of mongodb documents in a collection
such that each document has a unique timestamp and represents data for 1 minute

let each document === 1 minute
i want to fetch data in such a way that when api has param values as

timeframe:'1m' & limit = 30 he should get last 30 documents as single document (grouped)
timeframe:'2m' & limit = 30 he should get last 60 documents as single document (grouped)
timeframe:'5m' & limit = 10 he should get last 50 documents as single document (grouped)

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("63049944031441c5312f4954"),
    "name" : "kucoin:ADA/USDT",
    "exchange" : "kucoin",
    "timeframe" : "1m",
    "open" : 0.451433,
    "high" : 0.451777,
    "low" : 0.451433,
    "close" : 0.451585,
    "volume" : 1042.7538,
    "timestamp" : 1661185920000.0,
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: Can you provide exactly what the output you expect? it's not clear what you mean by "grouped"

Comment: let suppose we have 100 documents i want 50 docs
where every doc is a combination of 2 docs combine via aggregate

Comment: its like merging two docs as one and getting 50 out of total 100 documents

Comment: how do you "combine" the "exchange" field?

Comment: i dont know i am trying to figure this out

Comment: awaiting your help @TomSlabbaert

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.